# Is there a way to organize a column in R according to specific values?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, I have a data frame with a column for ID numbers:

data = c(3, 4, 5, 30010, 30020, 30030, 30040, 56010, 56020, 56030)

And I want to list all the longer numbers according to the shorter numbers, i.e., list all the numbers that start with 3 with 3, all the numbers that start with 4 with 4, etc. I have tried many different things but I think I am missing something. I would prefer an answer that uses dplyr, thanks.

Edit: An example of what I would like to achieve is a column that looks like this
|IDs|
|:---|
|3|
|30010|
|30020|
|30030|
|4|
|40010|
|40020|
|40030|

and so on.... I have a lot more IDs but for time and space saving purposes I'll just start here.

Comment: Try `data[order(as.character(data))]`.

Comment: Or `data[order(as.numeric(substr(data, 1, 1)))]`

Comment: Please provide an example output of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: These solutions almost work, however there are other numbers that are not getting picked up. I will try to edit my question and elaborate.

Comment: So why is `30040` in your data but not the expected output?

Comment: Apologies @Gnueghoidune, the numbers are made up so I was inconsistent in my usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data creation similar to yours:

```
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(c(3, 4, 5, 30010, 40010, 40020, 40030, 30020, 30030, 30040, 56010, 56020, 56030)) 
names(data) = c("ID")
```

Code to order as the example. It gives an output as the snip

```
data2 <- data[order(as.character(data$ID)),]
data2 <- data2 %>% as.data.frame()
```

[image]

Comment: @ Dutta This worked, thank you! Is it possible to use this code on multiple columns at once? For example: data2 <- data[order(as.character(c(data$ID, data$varB))),]

Comment: It is possible. ```data_id[order(as.character(data_id$ID), as.character(data_id$ID2)),]``` But again it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Please note, if you first column is sorted, the 2nd column won't be sorted the same way. For example, if you 1st row in ID column has 3 and ID2 column has 6, by doing this, its not going to put 3 in the ID2 column